# How to getch json api and export it's data to other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, fetch

I'm trying to call my JSON API and save the data to make available to other files, like a data loader file every time I restart the server it reloads the data from that file eliminating the need to request the API in every file, I keep trying but either I'm stuck behind a promise or async function

controller

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const json = fetch("url").then(res => res).catch(error => error);
module.exports = json;
```

Comment: Use ES6 modules instead of CommonJS modules. ES6 modules have top-level `await`.

Comment: The issue with asynchrony is, it can't be made to "go away" - you have to deal with it in your code

Comment: using ES6 the problem was resolved, thanks